# How to break on Garbage Collection?

Tags: garbage-collection, clr, windbg

How do I have to set a breakpoint in WinDGB in order to see the call to `GC.Collect()`? I already tried `bp clr!SVR::GCHeap::GarbageCollect` but it doesn't work...

I'm using .NET 4.5.1.

Answer (score 2):

Never mind! I just figured it out:

```
bp clr!WKS::GCHeap::GarbageCollect
```